# Bad Access in Custom Textfield Framework Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I have successfully created one custom framework called **DynamicFramework**, in which font is dynamically set according to the current device for all `UITextField` outlet. The framework is successfully built.

Now when I integrate that framework in my demo project. On running the code, I am getting a **bad access error** in `viewDidLoad` method

**Code used in the Framework method**

```
open class DynamicFontTextfield: UITextField {

open func adjustFontSizeWRTScreen() {

        switch UIDevice.current.screenType {

        case .iPhones_4_4S:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize)
            break

        case .iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 0)
            break

        case .iPhones_6_6s_7_8:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 1)
            break

        case .iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 2)
            break

        case .iPhones_X_XS:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 2)
            break

        case .iPhone_XR:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 2)
            break

        case .iPhone_XSMax:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 2)
            break

        default:
            self.font = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 4)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**Error in output:**

[image]

The reference I have used here for creating a custom framework is here : [Develop a swift framework](https://medium.com/captain-ios-experts/develop-a-swift-framework-1c7fdda27bf1)

The framework I have used : [Dynamic Framework](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzhbyz9bk8wbi89/DynamicFramework.framework.zip?dl=0)

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have all the code you should be able to debug this and see exactly what line this happens at and the state of your text field instance.

Comment: I cannot trace any issue while debugging

Comment: can you try to throw the function in viewWillAppear ?

Comment: @MohmmadS Getting same error

Comment: can  you share your framework ?

Comment: I suspect this function of your framework doing problem self.font , add this function in safe check